# OpenThread API: How to get child table using OpenThread API?

Tags: openthread

I have the OpenThread CLI application and I would like to create UDP datagram with the payload consisted of child table information.

So my question is: **how to get child table info and which API should I use?**
I have done some research, and I consider to play with **otThreadGetChildInfoByIndex()** placed in for/while loop. Does it make sense??

Best regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `otThreadGetChildInfoByIndex()` is what you are looking for.

You can find an example in OpenThread's [CLI](https://github.com/openthread/openthread/blob/434e6bbffc26a5eef1f5e4f5733b8bd536c250a6/src/cli/cli.cpp#L833) implementation.

Answer (score 0):

There is a link to OpenThread Github issue opened by me: https://github.com/openthread/openthread/issues/5259

We discuss there an idea of `get_child_table()` function implementation.